# Eclipse 2020-12, RCP project export fails

Tags: java, eclipse, export, rcp

Just created simple example RCP project, runed it succesfully, but cannot run export wizard - it fails:

```
D:\workspace_JC2C\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:89: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\workspace_JC2C\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:582: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Users\kit.HOME-PC\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.900.v20201111-1557\scripts\genericTargets.xml:241: A problem occured while invoking the director.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\workspace_JC2C\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:582: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Users\kit.HOME-PC\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.900.v20201111-1557\scripts\genericTargets.xml:241: A problem occured while invoking the director.
```

I enabled logging in genericTargets.xml, an see in log:

```
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director]   Software being installed: com.portlab.rcptest 1.0.0.202101262001 (RCPTest 1.0.0.202101262001)
[p2.director]   Missing requirement: Rcptest 1.0.0.202101262001 (com.portlab.rcptest 1.0.0.202101262001) requires 'osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=15))' but it could not be found
[p2.director]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director]       From: com.portlab.rcptest 1.0.0.202101262001 (RCPTest 1.0.0.202101262001)
[p2.director]       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.portlab.rcptest [1.0.0.202101262001,1.0.0.202101262001]
```

Looking for solutions in inet, I see some similar problem was exist in previous versions, but no solutions provided helps.

Comment: Product Export is no longer supported. [tag:maven] and [tag:tycho] is the only supported way to export RCPs. For a tutorial see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: Made everething as in tutorial, but cannot compile project - got errors:

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Kit/eclipse-workspace/com.portlab.test/src/com/portlab/test/handlers/OpenHandler.java:[3,42] package org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations does not exist
.....
etc.

Comment: There is something wrong in your plug-ins setup. At a guess you have not put the plug-in dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF Require-Bundle or Import-Package entries, or your target platform is wrong, or....